# Clickable image using firebase push notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to send a clickable image via notification using firebase push notification, if yes where should I start to learn how to do it?

Comment: can you elaborate the question? What do you mean by sending clickable image thru push notif? you mean, the push notif will send a link (maybe from amazon web services?) of an image with a corresponding link which will be loaded by your app?

Comment: I mean when the user gets the notification, he can click on it and it will take him to a specific link.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. on fcm there two part of a push.
1)notification 
2)data.
notification part is totally managed by google.So you have to use data part.In data part send a base64 image string and in app decode it to image. see below

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
Jsonobject obj=new JsonObject(remoteMessage.getData());
String image=obj.getString(“image_base64_string”);
//which you have to send from your backend or firebase console using this key
//then decode this image to bitmap and setimage to the imageview
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
```

Comment: so I have to add a specific code in the android studio project to get it to work? or I can do that only with the google-services.json setup that i already made for the normal text push notification?

Comment: Should i put this code in MyFirebaseMessagingService.java?

Comment: yeap.in the messaging service class

Comment: I got a lot of errors like: Error:(248, 5) error: illegal start of type, Error:(248, 30) error: <identifier> expected, Error:(251, 36) error: illegal character: '\u201c', Error:(251, 56) error: illegal character: '\u201d'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send the  `"click_action" => "http://google.com"` in your notification payload for directing the click_action over the notification and wherever you want to redirect after users taps over the recieved notificaiton